# Grub stops at command prompt after cold start (dual-boot)

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I've installed Ubutunu 20.04 at my second disk beside Windows 10 at the first disk.
On a restart/reboot grub shows the normal menu.
But on a cold/power-off start grub stops at command prompt. :(

Only way to continue is to manually type 'exit' which shows the grub menu and I'am able to continue regulary.

But computers are made for automation - grub should show the menu.

This is what I tried so far:

- in BIOS I selected boot entry for ubuntu only (see image below)
- tried with SecureBoot OFF and ON
- reinstalled grub / update-grub
- used boot-repair (see https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hnCzGjqC3q/ )
- created a /boot/grub/device.map and rebuild with grub-customizer
- Tried to manually boot Ubuntu from grub prompt, like
  https://www.unix-ninja.com/p/Manually_booting_the_Linux_kernel_from_GRUB
  But Using 'ls', I wonder why I can't see/access the kernel image for ubuntu from the grub prompt?
  [image: grub with ls]
- running now on newest BIOS 8433 F.50 from 2020 (before was from 2018), see https://dpaste.com/77KG84KPG
- disabled hibernate and FAST BOOT

All environments use UEFI mode.
Output from efibootmgr -v:

```
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0003,0000
Boot0000  Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,5549af8a-b198-4f6d-ab56-cd417e3dd297,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...&................
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,5549af8a-b198-4f6d-ab56-cd417e3dd297,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,5549af8a-b198-4f6d-ab56-cd417e3dd297,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)
```

BIOS boot order is only efi grub partition for ubuntu I suppose:
[image]

Connected disks:

- First disk: GPT-formatted
- Second disk: formatted with GParted with ext4 and swap

This is my generated grub.cfg:
https://dpaste.com/CS9HMHMQ5

Does grub generate any logs which reports errors?

**Any help appreciated to let grub show the menu also at first boot time.**

### Additional Information:

- Hardware:
  Product Name: HP Pavilion Power 690-0513ng Ryzen 5 260
  Family: 103C_53311M HP Pavilion

### Current state:

Effect is a kind of random - sometimes grub comes up in menu, but most times after cold boot still the grub command prompt is shown.

Comment: Change your post of efibootmgr to efibootmgr -v, better to post link to summary report from Boot-Repair as it shows all of your boot configuration including the more detailed version of efibootmgr.

Comment: Have you tried with UEFI Secure Boot off. What brand/model system? HP's typically do not recognized changes to boot order with efibootmgr which grub uses. It will boot once then revert to Windows. Have you updated UEFI to latest available?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance oldfred. I'am now running on newest BIOS as of 06.07.2020 and run update-grub once. Effect is a kind of toggle - one time grub comes up in menu and the other cold boot again only to grub command prompt. And so on in a row of boot actions. Really confusing...

Comment: Usually HP's revert to booting Windows. Only change from within UEFI changes permanently to Ubuntu entry. I do not normally cold boot, and have an older Intel system that just works. Someone with HP & AMD may be able to help.

Comment: Done more tests now:
Effect is a kind of random - sometimes grub comes up in menu, but most times after cold boot still the grub command prompt is shown.

Comment: Is fast boot on, and system booting faster than drive is up to speed or fully mounted?

Comment: In HP's BIOS I see no fast startup option. I used in Win10 'powercfg /hibernate off' to prevent any fast startup processes.

Comment: Fast Boot is an UEFI setting. I think Microsoft required it as Windows is so slow booting. It assumes no changes to system configuration, so UEFI/BIOS does not scan system for changes. What was written to drive in the way of configuration previously is then reused & boot immediately started. Microsoft then added fast start up/hibernation in Windows and required vendors to add tiny SSD as boot drives. Now many systems have larger SSD, so boot SSD not required. But all that for a slow booting system to make it seem faster.

Comment: Already learned a lot the last day. But I can't figure out how to show the Fast Boot is an UEFI setting. When I enter BIOS like the earlier screenshot shows, there is no such setting. Trying to go through F11 Troubleshoot and then to UEFI/BIOS brings me exactly to the same BIOS screen. 
As USB boot is enabled and it's fast booting method I still assume that the fast boot option is disabled. 
Is there a Linux command which can get this exact setting for fast boot from UEFI bios?

Comment: Not in the boot menu screen but the UEFI set up screen. HP - escape + F9 for boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios setup

Comment: Yes, understand. Sorry, meant F10 BIOS. It's quite sparse without fastboot setting, but I figured out how to show the disabled function on Win10. Fast boot is disabled.
Btw. stackexchange suggests a chat - how can I contact you via chat, so I would sent some more screenshots of the disabled fast boot.

Comment: The stack exchange site is good for one question and then an answer. But where a user needs more detailed instructions the Ubuntu Forum (or other forums) are often better. We both have to be online at same time, and I am typically only on for a bit the off doing something else.

Comment: I don't know if this hepls, but I am in a very similar situation, on an ASUS TUF A17 Gaming laptop, with Windows and Linux Mint, installed on two separate hard drives. The Grub resides on the drive where Linux is.
I observe the same random behavior: sometimes I get the prompt (and by giving the 'exit' command I go to the boot menu), sometimes I correctly have the boot menu right away.

Comment: Issue is still unresolved.